# Custom Constraint Validator with Database Connection Dependency Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm adding a custom validation query to a Symfony2 project.

[The docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) lack a complete example, and I'm not sure how to actually inject the database connection into the Validator Class.  I've created the service in my config, added the validatedBy alias method in my Constraint class, and set up this in my Validator Class:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

class ZipDatabaseValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    /**
     *
     * @var Connection
     */
    private $connection;

   public function __construct(Connection $dbalConnection)  {

        $this->connection = $dbalConnection;
    }

    public function validate($zipcode, Constraint $constraint)
    {

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM zip_table WHERE zip_code = ?';
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql); 
         ...
```

Here's my service config:

```
validator.node.zip_in_database:
        class: Acme\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\ZipDatabaseValidator
        arguments: [@database_connection]
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: zip_in_database }
```

I keep getting errors, in this case:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Acme\Bundle\Validator\Constraints\ZipDatabaseValidator::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Connection, none given,

How the heck to I set this up as a service or otherwise inject the database connection?

Comment: Read the part of the manual page you posted where it says:  Constraint Validators with Dependencies

Comment: Hi thanks gview.  I followed that part of the manual but there's incomplete detail on how to implement a validator constraint as a service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
validator.node.zip_in_database:
    class: Acme\Bundle\Validator\Constraint\ZipDatabaseValidator
    arguments: [@database_connection]
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: zip_in_database }
```

You must pass doctrine as an argument to your [Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

### Edit

Make sure the alias is the same as the validatedBy method returns!
in your case:

```
//Acme\Bundle\Validator\Constraint\ZipDatabase class
public function validatedBy()
{
    return 'zip_in_database';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gintro.  I updated the question with my config.  I'm passing the connection.  I think the problem is that I can't figure out how to use the Validator class as a service.

Comment: So you got your validator database connection sorted out.  Did you also make a constraint class?  The constraint class is what you use in your code.  It in turn accesses the validator class.  It's all in the cookbook example.

Comment: The alias in your service.yml `zip_in_database` must be the same as your validateBy method in your Constraint class returns! (return 'zip_in_database').

Comment: That works, I think I had the wrong alias!  Also I removed "parent::__construct();" from the constructor, that wasn't needed.  Thanks for your help, it is hard to understand the interplay between the DIC and the two different Validator classes.

Comment: @Acyra Glad to know it worked. It can be confusing sometimes, i know.
Had some trouble to with it.