# Get entity manager in custom validator

Tags: validation, symfony

I would like to know if it is possible to get the entity manager to reach repository in a custom validator.

I tried to declare the validator as a service and give the "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" argument.

But of course it does not work because, obviously I dont call the service when I add my validator as an annotation in the entity.

Is there a way to reach the repository in my custom validator that I called via an annotation in the entity to validate?

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator

class UniqueKeyValidator extends ConstraintValidator {
  public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {
    $entity = $this->context->getRoot()->getData();
    ... calling entity repository .....
  }
}
```

My service :

```
app.validator.unique:
    class: MyBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueKeyValidator
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator }
```

Comment: can you post the code of your validator? Configuration included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can [register validator as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies). And Symfony will check service container first when it will be going to create validator's instance.

It's just you probably forgot to add appropriate tag

Example from Symfony's doc:

```
services:
    validator.contains_alphanumeric:
        class: AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsAlphanumericValidator
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator }
```

Comment: Even with the tag it does not work : Argument 1 passed to UniqueKeyValidator::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given

Comment: Have added `arguments` property with appropriate configuration to pass doctrine in the service configuration? The example from Symfony's doc which I presented doesn't contain that. It only shows how to register a validator as a service.

Comment: the answer seems to be there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371267/custom-constraint-validator-with-database-connection-dependency-symfony2